Nest can't resolve dependencies of the service with single empty import
After starting the nest application I see the following error:
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?). Please make sure that the argument dependency at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.

Potential solutions:
- Is AuthModule a valid NestJS module?
- If dependency is a provider, is it part of the current AuthModule?
- If dependency is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AuthModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing dependency */ ]
  })

Here is an AppModule:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AuthModule } from './auth';

@Module({
  imports: [AuthModule]
})
export class AppModule {}


AuthModule:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserModule } from '@/user';
import { AuthController } from './auth.controller';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Module({
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  imports: [UserModule]
})
export class AuthModule {}

AuthService:
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserService } from '@/user';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(@Inject() private readonly userService: UserService) {}
}

UserModule:
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';

import { UserService } from './user.service';

@Module({
  providers: [UserService],
  exports: [UserService]
})
export class UserModule {}

And UserService:
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {}

As you can see, AuthModule is a valid NestJS module, dependency (userService) is a provider and and it's exported from UserModule, that is imported within AuthModule.
Considering that the errors indicated in the error message above are absent, I cannot understand what the problem is then.

I see you are importing UserModule from path '@/user';. I am guessing you are using index.ts files. Is it possible that you have a circular dependency in imports in index.ts files? Because that may be a reason

Any service in use by AuthController?

@Alejandro only AuthService

@Moti I tried to remove all the index.ts files but the error persisted

Okay, remove @Inject decorator in the constructor  then because it is unnecessary, if it does not help I do not know what is wrong

@Moti I removed decorator and the error disappeared. Tell why @Inject was unneccessarry

@lian I provided explanation as an answer

It is extremely easy to manage dependencies in Nest.js because they are resolved just by type. It means @Inject() decorator is redundant and you should only pass the service in constructor like this
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly userService: UserService) {}
}

but why is it redundant?
@Inject() decorator is used to to inject a dependency based on an injection token. It means that for UserService the injection token should be used like this @Inject(UserService) because the type is an automatically resolved injection token in this case.
Keep in mind that injection tokens can be types (class names), strings or symbols. This depends on how the provider with which it is associated was defined. Providers defined with the @Injectable() decorator use the class name. Custom Providers may use strings or symbols as the injection token.
